# whether to use a powershell pipeline or use powershell RunspaceInvoke to execute scripts

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a design query as regards the usage of the powershell pipeline versus the RunspaceInvoke method for the exectuion of single standalone scripts.  I know that the pipeline as used is, according to msdn, like an "assembly line". As i'm only excuting single standalone scripts, do I need to use it at all. Whats the pro's and con's.

Bob.

Comment: Somebody must have an opinion on this!
Whats best.

Comment: I too would like to know the difference. I've seen where both are used and would like to have more information on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260597/invoking-powershell-script-with-arguments-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Forgot this. I've implemented it using pipeline, and its fast and efficient.