# Invoking PowerShell Script with Arguments from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PowerShell script stored in a file. In Windows PowerShell, I execute the script as
`.\MergeDocuments.ps1 "1.docx" "2.docx" "merge.docx"`

I want to call the script from C#. Currently I am using Process.Start as follows which works perfectly:
`Process.Start(POWERSHELL_PATH, string.Format("-File \"{0}\" {1} {2}", SCRIPT_PATH, string.Join(" ", filesToMerge), outputFilename));`

I want to run it using `Pipeline` class, something like the below code but I don't know how to pass the arguments (keep in mind that I don't have named arguments, I am just using $args)

```
// create Powershell runspace
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

// create a pipeline and feed it the script text (AddScript method) or use the filePath (Add method)
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command command = new Command(SCRIPT_PATH);
command.Parameters.Add("", ""); // I don't have named paremeters
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

Comment: any final solution with full source ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just found it in one of the comments to another question

In order to pass arguments to the $args pass null as the parameter name, e.g. `command.Parameters.Add(null, "some value");`

The script is called as:
`.\MergeDocuments.ps1 "1.docx" "2.docx" "merge.docx"`

Here is the full code:

```
class OpenXmlPowerTools
{
    static string SCRIPT_PATH = @"..\MergeDocuments.ps1";

    public static void UsingPowerShell(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename)
    {
        // create Powershell runspace
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

        // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command command = new Command(SCRIPT_PATH);
        foreach (var file in filesToMerge)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(null, file);
        }
        command.Parameters.Add(null, outputFilename);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

        pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really wish that worked for me. I still get the same ParameterBindingException was unhandled error trying anything like this. It makes no sense.

Comment: If you try make "" instead of null then it will work. Then you will not get that ParameterBindingException

Comment: Also check your PS script