# call a remote powershell script with parameters from c# program

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have the next piece of code that works calling a remote powershell script ( the script is into the remote system ) but I would like to send parameters to script:

c# method:

```
public void RemoteConnection() 
{
   connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, remoteMachineName, 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, credentials);
   runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
   runspace.Open();
   Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(path);
   var results = pipeline.Invoke();
   foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

I tried to send parameters with CommandParameter but I obtained an error message:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command myCommand = new Command(path);
CommandParameter testParam0 = new CommandParameter("suma");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam0);
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("x", "89");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);
CommandParameter testParam2 = new CommandParameter("y", "11");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam2);
pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
```

Error Message:

```
{"Cannot perform operation because operation \"NewNotImplementedException at offset 76 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0\r\n\" is not implemented."}
```

I can call my powershell script(which is into my remote system ) in this way:

```
PS C:\grace\powershell> .\script1.ps1  -suma -x 9 -y 19
28
PS C:\grace\powershell> .\script1.ps1  -suma "9" "19"
28
```

How can I send through c# program parameters for my powershell script?

Comment: This has been asked in the past, see how to achieve this here by looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260597/invoking-powershell-script-with-arguments-from-c-sharp

Comment: @MattGartman I tried as the post suggest but I always obtain the error message "Cannot perform operation because operation ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it worked for me:

```
public void RemoteConnection() 
{
  connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, remoteMachineName, 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, credentials);
        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(path);

        Command myCommand = new Command(path);
        CommandParameter testParam0 = new CommandParameter("-suma");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam0);

        CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("x", "34");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);
        CommandParameter testParam2 = new CommandParameter("y", "11");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam2);

        pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
        var results = pipeline.Invoke();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
          Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

Note I'm sending the path to CreatePipeline and also to create a new Command (Maybe is necessary a further review)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you: 
http://com2kid.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/remotely-executing-commands-in-powershell-using-c/

Setting all the command together.