# How to pass parameters to a powershell script using c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I want to execute a powershell script via winforms and get well-formatted output. I managed to get it to work but now I need to pass parameters to my script. I can't manage to make that happen.

Here is my RunScript function :

```cs
        private string RunScript(string scriptFile)
        {
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
            Command script = new Command(scriptFile);
            script.Parameters.Add("COM_USERNAME", usernameBox.Text);
            script.Parameters.Add("COM_PASSWORD", passwordBox.Text);
            script.Parameters.Add("installDir", installDirBox.Text);
            script.Parameters.Add("TEMPVAULT_PATH", tempVaultBox.Text);
            script.Parameters.Add("MAX_REQ_LIMIT", maxReqLimBox.Text);
            script.Parameters.Add("MAX_BUFF_LIMIT", maxBuffLimBox.Text);
            pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(script.ToString());
            pipeLine.Commands.Add("Out-String");
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeLine.Invoke();
            runSpace.Close();

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject item in results)
            {
                strBuilder.AppendLine(item.ToString());
            }

            return strBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

And this is the script that I am trying with:

```
param (
  [bool]   $STARTSERVICE = $false ,
  [bool]   $INSTALL = $false ,
  [bool]   $INSTALL_DASHBOARD = $false,
  [bool]   $DASHBOARD_SETTINGS = $false,
  [bool]   $DASHBOARD_CREATENEWDB = $false,
  [bool]   $DALIM_SETTINGS = $false,
  [bool]   $INSTALLIIS = $true,
  [bool]   $FIRST_INSTALL = $true,
  [bool]   $RECOVERY = $false,
  [string] $COM_USERNAME,
  [string] $COM_PASSWORD,
  [string] $RECOVERY_ADM_NAME,
  [string] $RECOVERY_ADM_PWD,
  [string] $Windows2012DVDLetter = "F:",
  [string] $COM_UNCPATH,
  [string] $installDir = "C:\Program Files\App\",
  [string] $TEMPVAULT_PATH = "C:\TempVault",
  $SOAP_MaxPostSize = 4294967295,
  $MAX_REQ_LIMIT = 500000000,
  $MAX_BUFF_LIMIT = 500000000

)

Write-Output "`nUsername = " $COM_USERNAME
Write-Output "`nPassword = " $COM_PASSWORD
Write-Output "`nCOM_UNCPATH = " $COM_UNCPATH
Write-Output "`nMaximum Request Limit = " $MAX_REQ_LIMIT
Write-Output "`nMaximum Buff Limit = " $MAX_BUFF_LIMIT
Write-Output "`nIsFirstInstall = " $FIRST_INSTALL
Write-Output "`nInstallation Directory = " $installDir
Write-Output "`nTempVault Path = " $TEMPVAULT_PATH
Write-Output "`nRestriction level = " $RESTRICT_LVL
```

I have output with only the pre-registered in the script values showing, but the ones I'm trying to show (textboxes inputs) don't. Have I missed something?

Comment: From this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260767/8071045) it seems that paramters should be set up as: Parameters.Add(<value>, <paramName>)

Comment: No @Mahan.A it don't seems to work that way, in his case he is passing values without a param name so he gets only the value (file) and the paramName is null. But thanks!

Comment: @Mahan.A., to add to Asuar's comment: There are several [`Command.Parameters.Add()` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.commandparametercollection.add), but the one of interest is `void Add(string name, System.Object value)`, which shows that the parameter name goes _first_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following assumes that `scriptFile` is the *path* of a `*.ps1` file, not that file's *content* (a string containing Powershell code).
See the bottom section for how to handle the latter case.

---

You can greatly **simplify your invocation**:

```
private string RunScript(string scriptFile)
{
  using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    ps.AddCommand(scriptFile) // Be sure to pass a *full path*
        .AddParameter("COM_USERNAME", usernameBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("COM_PASSWORD", passwordBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("installDir", installDirBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("TEMPVAULT_PATH", tempVaultBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("MAX_REQ_LIMIT", maxReqLimBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("MAX_BUFF_LIMIT", maxBuffLimBox.Text)
      .AddCommand('Out-String'); // Add a pipeline segment
    // Return the 1st (and in this case only) output object, as a string.
    return ps.Invoke<string>()[0]; 
  }
}
```

Using `PowerShell.Create()` creates an instance of class [**`PowerShell`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell), which provides a **higher-level API** based on an implicitly created runspace:

- Methods can be chained.
- Calling `.AddCommand()` repeatedly automatically adds new pipeline segments.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(script.ToString());`

The `.AddScript()` method is for adding arbitrary pieces of *PowerShell code*, not for adding `Command` instances with associated parameters.
(`Command` instances represent either a PowerShell command such as `Out-String` or the name / path of an external executable or the path<sup>[1]</sup> to a script file (`*.ps1`)).

By stringifying the `Command` instance stored in `script` with `.ToString()`, you're effectively just passing the *script path* as the command to execute - all the parameters you've added with `.AddParameter()` are lost, which is why you only saw the *default* parameter values in the script's output.

Instead, **you should have added your `Command` instance as follows**:

```
pipeLine.Commands.Add(script)
```

---

**If `scriptFile` is not a *file path*, but the *contents* of a script file** (a string containing PowerShell code):

<sup>As you've since clarified, this is your actual use case, because the script is embedded as a *resource* in your executable that you pass with `RunScript(Properties.Resources.<the script>)`</sup>

Adapt the simplified approach at the top as follows:

```
// If `scriptFile` is the *contents* of a *.ps1 file,
// add it as a script [block] with .AddScript(),
// then add parameters (and the additional pipeline command).
ps.AddScript(scriptFile) 
        .AddParameter("COM_USERNAME", usernameBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("COM_PASSWORD", passwordBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("installDir", installDirBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("TEMPVAULT_PATH", tempVaultBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("MAX_REQ_LIMIT", maxReqLimBox.Text)
        .AddParameter("MAX_BUFF_LIMIT", maxBuffLimBox.Text)
  .AddCommand('Out-String'); // Add a pipeline segment
```

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell only allows by-name-only executions (e.g., `foo.ps1`) for executables / scripts located in a directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Otherwise, a file *path* must be specified, and it's safest to use a *full path*, because .NET's current directory usually differs from PowerShell's.</sup>