# How to pass parameters to a powershell script executed from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, arguments

I have the following Powershell script :

```
   param(
    [string] $Source ,
    [string] $Target ,
    [string] $UserId  
)
Set-Location "C:\My folder"
& "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "index.js" $Source $Target $UserId
```

I need to execute it from a C# application, so I have this code:

```
var process = new Process();
string parameters = string.Format(" -Source {0} -Target {1} -UserId {2} ", Source, Target, UserName);
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"&'" + ScriptName + "'\" ";
process.Start();
string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

This works in invoke my script, but I don't know how to pass the parameters that I have in the variables.

I already tried using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(); but this way doesn't execute my script.

Comment: Did you find this during your searching for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260597/invoking-powershell-script-with-arguments-from-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, I tried that exactly piece of code, and did'nt work.  just do not execute my script file.  Like nothing happens...

Comment: If I type this at the CMD command line: `C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "get-date -year 2010"` then Powershell starts up and runs `get-date -year 2010`.  Try something like that.  I.E., set the arguments to `-command "get-date -year 2010"` (substituting your script and your script arguments)

Comment: Where do you declare `ScriptName`? Also, the argument line is unclear... Check out this article on how to call the exe:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Oh, sure.  I declared that variable a little before that piece of code. Like this:  string ScriptName = "c:\\code\\MyFolder\\data\\script\\StepOne.ps1";     and, I need the C# code to pass the parameters, not the powershell script, because I already have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can use C# v6+ interpolated strings, and assuming that the arguments you're trying to pass to script `ScriptName` are stored in variables `Source`, `Target`, and `UserId`:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-File \"{ScriptName}\" \"{Source}\" \"{Target}\" \"{UserId}\"";
```